# Combination of how to pick a team of 4?

Tags: combinatorics

> A software development team of four must be chosen from three women
>   and four men. In how many ways can two men and two women be chosen?

In this question I have the answer a follows

$C_2^4$ for the men

$C_2^3$ for the women

The ways which two men and two women be chosen

$C_2^4 \cdot C_2^3 = 18$

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: @  Alexander Geldhof: Thanks :)

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to choose two men from four:

$4\choose 2$=$\frac{4!}{(2!)(4-2)!}=\frac{4\cdot3\cdot2!}{2!2!}=\frac{12}{2}=6$

The number of ways to choose two women from three:

$3\choose 2$=$\frac{3!}{(2!)(3-2)!}=\frac{3\cdot2!}{2!1!}=\frac{3}{1}=3$

Thus, the number of ways to choose four members from two men and two women is:

$4 \choose 2$ $\cdot$ $3 \choose 2$ = $6\cdot3$=$18$